# CakePHP - Getting NULL from a session variable when trying to add to a Model's options array

Tags: session, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.3.0. I searched in the manual for quite awhile and searched the internet, but I haven't found the answer. Here is my high level scenario:

** Basically, I'm just trying to add a variable and a value to the options array, so that when cakephp builds the SQL insert into statement, it has this required column and value. **

- The user logs in to a web page with username and password
- Within the controller, I use the model to query my user table to get the id # of the user
- I put the ID # into a session variable
- Next, the user is logged in and then fills out a web form and submits
- In my controller, I attempt to add to the model's options array with the value of that id stored in the session variable (this is where my trouble lies)....see details below

In my UsersController, I have this code snippet:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {                    
                $condition = array("User.username" => $this->request->data['User']['username']);
                $this->Session->write('userId', $this->User->find('first', 
                            array (
                            'conditions' => array ($condition),
                            'fields' => array ('User.id'))));                   
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());                   
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my ActivitiesController, I have this:

```
class ActivitiesController extends AppController {

    var $components = array('Session');

    public function createActivity() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
              $this->Activity->create();
             $user = $this->Session->read('userId');
            //debug($user);
            debug($user['User']['id']);
            $ownerID = ($user['User']['id']);
            $this->Activity->set(array('owner_id' => $ownerID));
            if ($this->Activity->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'home'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
```

My debug will print a value of 5, which is what I would expect to see. But, what I get is a database error, which outputs on the webpage the SQL INSERT INTO code and it tells me that my owner_id cannot be NULL. Which is correct, since that is how I setup this up in the DB table.

So, I'm getting a NULL when trying to put the value of the ID from the session variable into my options array. I would still consider myself more of a beginner to cakephp. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `array ($condition)` should be `$conditions` - its already an array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do what the framework already does.

The login function doesn't need more then this:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your logged in now.');
            $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'createActivity'));
        }
        else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect', 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

And in your activity controller

```
public function createActivity() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Activity']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->Activity->create();
        if ($this->Activity->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'home'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

AppController should contain

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Auth',
        'Session',
    );

}
```

It is also recommended to follow Cake's conventions, if you link Activity to User, set the foreign key name to user_id and not owner_id
[Model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Comment: Hey kaklon, thanks for the answer! I have this working now. Looks like I need to take a timeout and read the documentation some more.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use $_SESSION to store user information. The Auth component is already handling everything. You can get the user id in your controller by calling `$this->Auth->user('id');` I think using that variable might solve your problem.

See the API docs here: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AuthComponent.html#method-AuthComponentuser

Comment: I definitely need to read the documentation closer on auths and sessions. Thanks for the input! I have this working now....and cleaned up my code.